# Which band to use for LSWI?

Tags: remote-sensing, sentinel-2, vegetation-index

I have a sentinel 2 L1C data and I am trying to calculate the Land Surface Water Index (LSWI) using the NIR and SWIR bands. As the Sentinel 2 data is having 2 SWIR bands (B11 and B12), I am confused about which one to use for LSWI calculation

Answer (score 1):

You want bands compatible with MODIS bands B02 (841-875 nm) and B06 (1628-1652 nm).

Check out the Sentinel-2 specification [SENTINEL-2 Radiometric Resolutions](https://sentinel.esa.int/web/sentinel/user-guides/sentinel-2-msi/resolutions/radiometric) to find:

- Band 08A: Narrow Near InfraRed (848 ~ 880 nm)
- Band 11:  SWIR (1540 ~ 1685 nm)

So the band combination becomes `(B08A - B11) / (B08A + B11)`.

Band 12 range (2070 ~ 2340 nm) is far off for your requirement.

Comment: Will it give me wrong results if i use Band 8 instead of Band 8A ?

Comment: @GopalakrishnanB I cannot say using Band 8A & 11 combination is correct, as LSWI was meant for MODIS data. But I certainly not recommend to use Band 8. Not only its broader band range, you will struggle with its spatial resolution (10m) is different from SWIR Band11 (20m).

Comment: OK. A final question. What is the ideal range value for LSWI ? I couldn't arrive at a conclusion from the literature's I have come across.

Comment: LSWI is an empirical index, so try not to use it alone as definitive criteria. If it is hard to find ground truth, then using LSWI together with other index like NDVI may help.